# Video problems in phonegap android build

Tags: android, html, cordova

My html5 video wont work on android phonegap build,
when i press on the video's play button i get the following errors in 
the eclipse console:

```
MediaPlayer(3349): Uri is  <URL suppressed>
MediaPlayer(3349): error (1, -2147483648) 
MediaPlayer(3349): Error (1,-2147483648)
```

Im using video js, and my html code is as follows:

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-intro-skin nilfiskvideo" controls preload="auto"  poster="" data-setup="{}">
<source src="./assets/movies/intro/Intro_Film_Edit.mp4"   type="video/mp4"  />
<source src="./assets/movies/intro/Intro_Film_Edit.webm"  type="video/webm" />
<source src="./assets/movies/intro/Intro_Film_Edit.ogg"   type="video/ogg"  />
</video>
```

I might add that my javascript looks like this:

```
var myPlayer = _V_("example_video_1");


myPlayer.src([
   { type: "video/mp4",  src: this.model.get("mp4") },
   { type: "video/webm", src: this.model.get("webm") },
   { type: "video/ogg",  src: this.model.get("ogg")}
])

myPlayer.play();
```

thanks.

**Edit:**

Okay so now i have try'ed the different solution  proposals including using a plain native video object (no video-js).

but I still get the URL suppressed error.

Is there some permission  that I need to set to allow the android device to play local media files, or should the videos be located in a certain folder?

Comment: paste your code what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

```
  <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-intro-skin nilfiskvideo" controls preload="auto"  poster="" data-setup="{}">
     <source src="movies/intro/Intro_Film_Edit.mp4"   type='video/mp4; codecs="vc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'  />
     <source src="movies/intro/Intro_Film_Edit.webm"  type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
     <source src="movies/intro/Intro_Film_Edit.ogg"   type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'  />
  </video>

<script>
 $( document ).ready(function() {
   //This is on load , You can also use 'example_video_1' click event
   var video = $('#example_video_1').get(0);
   video.load();
   video.play();
 });
</script>
```

Comment: I will try the load call and see what happens :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<video class="video" class="video-js vjs-intro-skin nilfiskvideo" controls preload="auto"  poster="">
       <source src="./assets/movies/intro/Intro_Film_Edit.mp4"   type="video/mp4"  />
    <source src="./assets/movies/intro/Intro_Film_Edit.webm"  type="video/webm" />
    <source src="./assets/movies/intro/Intro_Film_Edit.ogg"   type="video/ogg"  />
    </video>
```